# SceneKit: How to create frozen SCNNode copy to perform hit test on background queue?

Tags: scenekit, ios11, hittest

Right now I perform face landmark detection and then use `SCNSceneRenderer.hitTest(cgPt, options: [.rootNode: faceNode])` on the resulting points to find the 3D positions of various landmarks. My face node is a child of `ARFaceAnchor` and has `ARSCNFaceGeometry`. The basic algorithm seems to work very well. However, for performance reasons, I dispatch feature detection and individual hit tests to a background queue, and it seems like this leads to a significant decrease in accuracy compared to when everything is performed synchronously.

Presumably, this is because I use a given `ARFrame` to find 2D landmarks, but by the time I perform the hit test asynchronously, there's no guarantee that my face node `SCNNode` is in the same position as it was when the frame was captured,  it's likely moved a little bit. (The face anchor is tracked/updated with `ARFaceTrackingConfiguration`).

Is there a way to create a "frozen" copy of the face node that I can pass along with the frame in order to perform hit tests asynchronously without the node's position changing in the meantime?

From what I understand, `clone()` and `copy()` don't provide what I'm looking for. I tried writing my own `frozenCopy()` function by setting a new SCNNode to the geometry and position of the original. However when I print the `worldPosition` of this node at the time of creation vs. time of hit test, it seems to have changed, even though I don't actually add it to the scene hierarchy... So I don't think it's behaving how I expect. Am I on the right track with this idea?

Any ideas would be very appreciated. Thanks so much!

```
extension SCNNode {
    func frozenCopy() -> SCNNode {
        // let scnCopy: SCNNode = self.copy() as! SCNNode
        // let scnCopy: SCNNode = self.clone()
        let scnCopy: SCNNode = SCNNode()
        scnCopy.geometry = self.geometry?.copy() as! SCNGeometry?
        scnCopy.transform = self.worldTransform

        // Setting more properties just in case...
        scnCopy.worldOrientation = self.worldOrientation
        scnCopy.worldPosition = self.worldPosition
        scnCopy.camera = self.camera?.copy() as! SCNCamera?
        scnCopy.light = self.light?.copy() as! SCNLight?
        scnCopy.pivot = self.pivot

        return scnCopy
    }
}
```

One solution I've considered is to try storing the face node and camera transforms to pass to a custom hit test function. If possible though, I'd like to use the SceneKit API hit test since I imagine this performs better than any function I write myself.

Comment: *However, for performance reasons, I dispatch feature detection and individual hit tests to a background queue* — have you found performance problems with hit testing on the main queue?

Comment: Well somewhat, since this is run on multiple consecutive frames. But the bigger performance hit is really the face landmark detection (Vision API), so that's really the piece I need to background. Given that, even if I perform the hit tests on the main queue, if the 2D points are found asynchronously, I think I'd still face the same problem.